# React js state duplicate issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am having an issue where attempting to push state values from an `onClick Handler` to array results in duplication

so, when you click, the add transaction button, it pushes the first transaction to the array, when you change the values of the form and click the button again, the new values overwrite the old ones and now both array entries display the last transaction only.

How do I fix this?

**Here is the code:**

```
function UserInput() {

    function Transaction(description, value, type) {
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    };

    const transactionList = [];
    const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState('');

    const newTransaction = () => {           
        setTransaction(new Transaction())   
    }

    const handleSelect = (event)=> {
        transaction.type = event.target.value
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(transactionList)
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="item info"> 
            <button onClick = {newTransaction}> new transaction </button>

            <form action='submit'>
                <select onChange = {handleSelect} >
                    <option defaultValue> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option> withdrawal </option>
                    <option> deposit </option>
                </select>

            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Description" onChange = { e => transaction.description = e.target.value} />

            <input type="number" placeholder="value" onChange = { e => transaction.value = e.target.value}/>
            
            <button type="submit" onClick = {e => {e.preventDefault()
                transactionList.push(transaction) 
                console.log(transaction) }
                }> Add Transaction </button>

            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserInput;
```

Comment: I would suspect your code works if you hit submit and then hit new.  You aren't changing what 'transaction` is, so even though you pushed it to an array you are still making changes to the same object (and then possibly pushing it again to the array which now has multiple copies of the same object reference)

Answer (score 0):

The component isn't re-rendering as expected because the React lifecycle isn't aware of `transactionList`, so doing `transactionList.push` wouldn't cause the component to re-render and display the new value.  A better way to do it would probably be to use `useState` with `transactionList`, which would hook into the react lifecycle.  You could do that like this:

```js
function UserInput() {
    ...

    const [transactionList, setTransactionList] = useState([]);
    const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState('');

    const addTransactionToList = transaction => {
      setTransactionList([...transactionList, transaction])
    }  

    return (
             ...
                
                <button type="submit" onClick = {e => {e.preventDefault()
                    addTransactionToList(transaction) 
                    console.log(transaction) }
                 }> Add Transaction </button>


             ...
    )
}

export default UserInput
```

Comment: hmmm, I'll try and get back to you... ignore the previous edit of this comment